# any countereample in measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

As we know, Lebesgue measurable function f is defined as all preimages of the open sets are Lebesgue measurable. So I'm wondering if this definition guarantee that the preimage of any Lebesgue measurable set is Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 0):

No - if $f$ is injective and sends any positive-measure set $B$ to null set $A$, then fix some nonmeasurable subset $C$ of $B$; the image $D$ of $C$ is a subset of $A$, which is null, and hence measurable. So $D$ is measurable with non-measurable preimage.

This is the only obstacle that can arise: if $f$ is measurable and the $f$-preimage of any null set is null, then the $f$-preimage of any measurable set is measurable (use the fact that measurable sets differ from a $G_\delta$ set by a null set).

Comment: How do you ensure that $f^{-1}U$ is measurable for open $U$?

Comment: @user254665 Sorry, the conditions above were *in addition to* measurability of $f$. It does take a bit of work to show that such a function exists.

Comment: The function $f(x) = x + C(x)$ is a homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ onto $[0,2]$ that takes the Cantor set onto a set of positive measure. Here $C$ is the Cantor function. So $f^{-1}$ will give a suitable example.

Comment: @zhw, thanks for that, and I still have one question: how to prove that any positive measurable set contains a non-measurable set?